# How can I get rid of this empty white space on the bottom?

Tags: android, xml, themes

I get this random margin at the bottom of one of my layouts. It seems to be pushing the background upwards which is why part of the top is cut off(might not be that noticeable. https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiTXe.png

All I did recently was change the theme of my app. My MainActivity's layout  doesn't show up like this, so i'm guessing it's a problem with this layout. Here's the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/choose_test_bg">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/ta_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="T-A"
            android:id="@+id/buttonA"
            android:onClick="onButton1Click"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/tb_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="T-B"
            android:id="@+id/buttonB"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:onClick="onButton1Click"/>

        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/tc_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="T-C"
            android:id="@+id/buttonC"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:onClick="onButton1Click"/>

        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/td_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="T-D"
            android:id="@+id/buttonD"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:onClick="onButton1Click"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">


        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/te_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="T-E"
            android:id="@+id/buttonE"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/tf_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="T-F"
            android:id="@+id/buttonF"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/tg_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="T-D"
            android:id="@+id/buttonG"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:onClick="onButton1Click"/>

        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/th_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="T-D"
            android:id="@+id/buttonH"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:onClick="onButton1Click"/>

    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to to set the height of the relativelayout to match_parent